# Avoiding accidental capture in structural pattern matching

Tags: python, defensive-programming, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

[This example](https://twitter.com/jakevdp/status/1359870794877132810) is being discussed as likely "gotcha" when using pattern matching:

```
NOT_FOUND = 400

retcode = 200
match retcode:
    case NOT_FOUND:
        print('not found')  

print(f'Current value of {NOT_FOUND=}')
```

This is an example of accidental capture with structural pattern matching. It gives this unexpected output:

```
not found
Current value of NOT_FOUND=200
```

This same problem comes up in other guises:

```
match x:
    case int():
        pass
    case float() | Decimal():
        x = round(x)
    case str:
        x = int(x)
```

In this example, `str` needs to have parentheses, `str()`.  Without them, it "captures" and the *str* builtin type is replaced with the value of *x*.

Is there a [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) practice that can help avoid these problems and provide early detection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Best practice

> Is there a defensive programming practice that can help avoid these problems and provide early detection?

Yes. Accidental captures are easily detected by always including what PEP 634 describes as an [irrefutable case block](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#irrefutable-case-blocks).

In plain language, that means a catchall case that always matches.

### How it works

Accidental captures always match. No more than one irrefutable case block is permitted.  Therefore, accidental captures are detected immediately when an intentional catchall is added.

### Fixing the first example

Just add a catchall [wildcard pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#wildcard-pattern) to the end:

```
match retcode:
    case NOT_FOUND:
        print('not found')
    case _:
        pass
```

That detects the problem immediately an gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: name capture 'NOT_FOUND' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

### Fixing the second example

Add a catchall [wildcard pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#wildcard-pattern) to the end:

```
match x:
    case int():
        pass
    case float() | Decimal():
        x = round(x)
    case str:
        x = int(x)
    case _:
        pass
```

Again the problem is detected immediately:

```
SyntaxError: name capture 'str' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```